# Can't create type with ‘id: ID! @unique’

Tags: prisma

I just setup the advanced boilerplate with the init command and added  the following to `datamodel.graphql`

```
type Spot {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  lat: String!
  long: String!
  name: String!
  fishes: [Species!]!
}

type Species {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  name: String!
  spots: [Spot!]!
}
```

When I try to do `prisma deploy` the public demo never starts up (500 error). As soon as I remove `id: ID! @unique` from type Species type it starts working. I tried doing `prisma reset` with the same issue. When I do `prisma seed -r` I get the following error message, note that `seed.graphql` just contains the boilerplate code.

> ERROR: All fields within 'Query' type should have unique names! Non-unique fields: 'species'.
>
> {
>     "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "All fields within 'Query' type should have unique names! Non-unique fields: 'species'.",
>         "requestId": "us1:api:cjhobke57sxok0b62n6f96ez4"
>       }
>     ],
>     "status": 500
>   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I was unable to figure it out exactly, if I change out the word "Species" for any other word it works. My guess is that it does not know how to properly pluralize "Species".

Comment: That's correct, this also happens for the model names "Homework" or "News" for example. See more here: https://github.com/prismagraphql/prisma/issues/1772